# ADXL345 Interrupt doesn't work

Tags: arduino, interrupts, accelerometer

I am using adxl345 with arduino. I am using sparkfun's library.  I am using adxl345 with I2C. I can read adxl345 value without any problem and I can detect inactivity and activity.

[githubSparkfunExampelCode](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_ADXL345_Arduino_Library/blob/master/examples/SparkFun_ADXL345_Example/SparkFun_ADXL345_Example.ino)I am trying to implement this example. If I don't use the interrupts, code is just work fine. I can detect everything.  I want to use interrupt so I try it but I couldn't get this work. Here is how I try:

```
/*  ********************************************* 

*  SparkFun_ADXL345_Example
*  Triple Axis Accelerometer Breakout - ADXL345 
*  Hook Up Guide Example 
*  
*  Utilizing Sparkfun's ADXL345 Library
*  Bildr ADXL345 source file modified to support 
*  both I2C and SPI Communication
*  
*  E.Robert @ SparkFun Electronics
*  Created: Jul 13, 2016
*  Updated: Sep 06, 2016
*  
*  Development Environment Specifics:
*  Arduino 1.6.11
*  
*  Hardware Specifications:
*  SparkFun ADXL345
*  Arduino Uno
*  *********************************************/

#include <SparkFun_ADXL345.h>         // SparkFun ADXL345 Library

/*********** COMMUNICATION SELECTION ***********/
/*    Comment Out The One You Are Not Using    */
//ADXL345 adxl = ADXL345(10);           // USE FOR SPI COMMUNICATION, ADXL345(CS_PIN);
ADXL345 adxl = ADXL345();             // USE FOR I2C COMMUNICATION

/****************** INTERRUPT ******************/
/*      Uncomment If Attaching Interrupt       */
int interruptPin = 2;                 // Setup pin 2 to be the interrupt pin (for most Arduino Boards)

boolean bool_1=true;
boolean bool_2=true;
/******************** SETUP ********************/
/*          Configure ADXL345 Settings         */
void setup(){

Serial.begin(9600);                 // Start the serial terminal
Serial.println("SparkFun ADXL345 Accelerometer Hook Up Guide Example");
Serial.println();

adxl.powerOn();                     // Power on the ADXL345

adxl.setRangeSetting(16);           // Give the range settings
                                    // Accepted values are 2g, 4g, 8g or 16g
                                    // Higher Values = Wider Measurement Range
                                    // Lower Values = Greater Sensitivity

adxl.setSpiBit(0);                  // Configure the device to be in 4 wire SPI mode when set to '0' or 3 wire SPI mode when set to 1
                                    // Default: Set to 1
                                    // SPI pins on the ATMega328: 11, 12 and 13 as reference in SPI Library 

adxl.setActivityXYZ(1, 1, 1);       // Set to activate movement detection in the axes "adxl.setActivityXYZ(X, Y, Z);" (1 == ON, 0 == OFF)
adxl.setActivityThreshold(75);      // 62.5mg per increment   // Set activity   // Inactivity thresholds (0-255)

adxl.setInactivityXYZ(1, 1, 1);     // Set to detect inactivity in all the axes "adxl.setInactivityXYZ(X, Y, Z);" (1 == ON, 0 == OFF)
adxl.setInactivityThreshold(75);    // 62.5mg per increment   // Set inactivity // Inactivity thresholds (0-255)
adxl.setTimeInactivity(10);         // How many seconds of no activity is inactive?

adxl.setTapDetectionOnXYZ(0, 0, 1); // Detect taps in the directions turned ON "adxl.setTapDetectionOnX(X, Y, Z);" (1 == ON, 0 == OFF)

// Set values for what is considered a TAP and what is a DOUBLE TAP (0-255)
adxl.setTapThreshold(50);           // 62.5 mg per increment
adxl.setTapDuration(15);            // 625 μs per increment
adxl.setDoubleTapLatency(80);       // 1.25 ms per increment
adxl.setDoubleTapWindow(200);       // 1.25 ms per increment

// Set values for what is considered FREE FALL (0-255)
adxl.setFreeFallThreshold(7);       // (5 - 9) recommended - 62.5mg per increment
adxl.setFreeFallDuration(30);       // (20 - 70) recommended - 5ms per increment

// Setting all interupts to take place on INT1 pin
//adxl.setImportantInterruptMapping(1, 1, 1, 1, 1);     // Sets "adxl.setEveryInterruptMapping(single tap, double tap, free fall, activity, inactivity);" 
                                                        // Accepts only 1 or 2 values for pins INT1 and INT2. This chooses the pin on the ADXL345 to use for Interrupts.
                                                        // This library may have a problem using INT2 pin. Default to INT1 pin.

// Turn on Interrupts for each mode (1 == ON, 0 == OFF)
adxl.InactivityINT(1);
adxl.ActivityINT(1);
adxl.FreeFallINT(1);
adxl.doubleTapINT(1);
adxl.singleTapINT(1);

attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), ADXL_ISR, RISING);   // Attach Interrupt

}

/****************** MAIN CODE ******************/
/*     Accelerometer Readings and Interrupt    */
void loop(){

// Accelerometer Readings
int x,y,z;   
adxl.readAccel(&x, &y, &z);         // Read the accelerometer values and store them in variables declared above x,y,z

// Output Results to Serial
/* UNCOMMENT TO VIEW X Y Z ACCELEROMETER VALUES */  
//Serial.print(x);
//Serial.print(", ");
//Serial.print(y);
//Serial.print(", ");
//Serial.println(z); 
if(bool_1)
{
    Serial.println("******inactive******");
    bool_1=false;
}
if(bool_2)
{
    Serial.println("******active******");
    bool_2=false;
}
//ADXL_ISR();
// You may also choose to avoid using interrupts and simply run the functions within ADXL_ISR(); 
//  and place it within the loop instead.  
// This may come in handy when it doesn't matter when the action occurs. 

}

/********************* ISR *********************/
/* Look for Interrupts and Triggered Action    */
void ADXL_ISR() {

// getInterruptSource clears all triggered actions after returning value
// Do not call again until you need to recheck for triggered actions
byte interrupts = adxl.getInterruptSource();

// Free Fall Detection
if(adxl.triggered(interrupts, ADXL345_FREE_FALL)){
    Serial.println("*** FREE FALL ***");
    //add code here to do when free fall is sensed
} 

// Inactivity
if(adxl.triggered(interrupts, ADXL345_INACTIVITY)){
    Serial.println("*** INACTIVITY ***");
    //add code here to do when inactivity is sensed
    bool_1=true;
}

// Activity
if(adxl.triggered(interrupts, ADXL345_ACTIVITY)){
    Serial.println("*** ACTIVITY ***"); 
    //add code here to do when activity is sensed
    bool_2=true;
}

// Double Tap Detection
if(adxl.triggered(interrupts, ADXL345_DOUBLE_TAP)){
    Serial.println("*** DOUBLE TAP ***");
    //add code here to do when a 2X tap is sensed
}

// Tap Detection
if(adxl.triggered(interrupts, ADXL345_SINGLE_TAP)){
    Serial.println("*** TAP ***");
    //add code here to do when a tap is sensed
} 
}
```

The output:

15:45:50.536 -> SparkFun ADXL345 Accelerometer Hook Up Guide
Example

15:45:50.570 ->

15:45:50.570 -> ******inactive******

15:45:50.603 -> ******active******

******inactive****** and ******active****** prints only 1 time because I started the boolean values true. After this nothing prints. How can I solve this ?

[ADXL345PDF](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adxl345.pdf)

My connections:

3.3V to VCC

GND to GND

PIN2 to INT1

SDA to SDA

SCL to SCL

Comment: Please include a schematic and a link to the device data sheet.

Comment: @Andyaka I added

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen I read the data sheet and I try to wrote code myself. I success everything (double tab, tab, activity, inactivity) but I couldn't get this work with interrupt so I decided to use library and example sketch that uses interrupt. I couldn't get this work it too.